# Install mplayer or alternative player with GPU acceleration on ARMv8

Tags: video, gpu, arch-arm

I have a custom board that is similar to Odroid C2 i.e. it is powered by Amlogic S905 with a Mali 450 GPU.

Support from Amlogic is limited, so I cannot turn to the manufacturer.

I am running Arch linux (Kernel 3.14, I know it is old, I'm ok with it.) on it and it works quite well for all my needs. The only additional thing I want it to do is be able to play videos using GPU acceleration using any open source player like mplayer or newer alternatives.

I know GPU acceleration can work on this board because I have played with another download of Arch linux from a custom Rom developer who has installed Kodi on it that is successfully able to use GPU acceleration on it with Kodi.

I'm at a loss on how to install mplayer and get it to use GPU. Any assistance with directions on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

mplayer version with GPU is named MPlayer VA-API. 
you may look with version if its supports your GPU familly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/224524)

Comment: @Kevdog777 and the upvoters: To me it seems this perfectly answers the question. To use the GPU, you need the VA-API version; that's what the OP seems to have missed. And the hint was added to first look whether this Mali is supported. What's wrong with the answer?

Comment: Thanks Francois! I'll spend some time with MPlayer VA-API and revert back to update.

Comment: @Philippos well the OP has asked for assistance in `installing` the software. This answer does not show how to install it. Yes it is a suggestion to use `MPlayer VA-API` but would be good to give step-by-step instructions on how to install it (to avoid confusion). Remember the OP asked: "I'm at a loss on how to install mplayer and get it to use GPU". So a little more detail is no harm - to me, this was more of a comment than an answer.